# LFS 9.1, step 6.9 (glibc-2.31) , breaks gcc

Tags: gcc, linux-from-scratch

I'm stuck os step 6.9 of LFS.
After launching make, the following command breaks gcc functionality

```
case $(uname -m) in
  i?86)
  ln -sfnv $PWD/elf/ld-linux.so.2 /lib ;;
  x86_64) ln -sfnv $PWD/elf/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib ;;
esac
```

Im'working on a 64 bit machine, so the second line is executed.

If I start gcc I get the following error :
gcc: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

so I'm unable to perform make check since gcc doesnt' work.

If I restore the original lib, (yes, i made a copy) gcc works correctly

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "restore the original lib" ?

Comment: simpy to copy the old file on the original location :
cp /lib/oldfile  /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: So presumably, at some prior time you did a `cp /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib/oldfile` What prompted you to make a backup copy of that "file"? This points to some other issue that you had to (try to) overcome before now.

Comment: yes, I did such a copy, because after the ln command I saw hen gcc did'nt work anymore. After several searches  I found the the culprit was the library. So I rebuild all the  project from the start until the step 6.9, where before issuing the command I made a copy of  the library. Evidently the configure/make commands create a library that does not works in this environment.

Comment: You rebuilt from the start of Chapter 6, or from page 1? Are you in chroot? Did you deviate from the book at all?

Comment: I did both operations more than once.
Finally I made a copy of /toos at the end of chapter 5, so that I could restart from chapter 6.1. And yes, I did chroot and followed slavishly every step of the book.

Comment: Now, rereading the manual, I note that the ln command is issued **before** any configure operations of chapter 6.9 , so the problem must have arisen before this chapter.
Using my /tools backup I'm going to restart from chapter 6,1, switcing the library back and forth before every chapter, and checking at every step the gcc funcionality.

Comment: please disregard my last notice. the pproblam arises **after** compiling glibc, and before make check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217121/discussion-between-maurizio-ferreira-and-rfmodulator).